# trying to connect to postgres (in a docker container) from Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, docker

I am playing around with Docker and wanted to setup postgreSQL in a docker container and then connect to it from a (non dockerized) Ruby on Rails app. Here's the docker compose file - I am following [this approach here](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2019/01/how-run-postgresql-docker-mac-local-development/).

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: "postgres:13"
    container_name: "postgres_dev"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "pgdev2021"
    ports:
      - "54320:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata://Users/thomas/Documents/Production/PostgreSQL/dbstorage

volumes:
  pgdata:
```

But when I then try to e. g. run "Rails db:prepare", I get this error:

```
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.54320"?
/Users/thomas/Documents/Websites/rails-frontend/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/thomas/Documents/Websites/rails-frontend/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/thomas/Documents/Websites/rails-frontend/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.54320"?
/Users/thomas/Documents/Websites/rails-frontend/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/thomas/Documents/Websites/rails-frontend/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/thomas/Documents/Websites/rails-frontend/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:prepare
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

When I check, the container IS running

EDIT: database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  port: 54320
  user: postgres

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db_development
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db_test
production:
  <<: *default
  database: db_production
  username: postgres
  password: <%= ENV['MY_DB_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Comment: Doesn't help, same error. I tried the line from below, docker exec.... bash, then psql, and that doesn't work neither. I can bash into docker, but psql gives the following error: "psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 54320 failed: Connection refused. Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?"

Comment: Inside the container you have to connect with `localhost:5432` not `54320`.

Comment: I am trying to connect from the host to the container.... I think I need to find the IP of the container somehow and then add that as "host" to my database.yml?

Answer (score 0):

If I want to start Postgres I always provide a user, password and initial db.

Are you trying to do inter-container networking or do you access from the host system? If it is intern-container networking, keep in mind by default the hostname of a service equals the service name.

Example compose file:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  postgres:
    image: "postgres:13"
    container_name: "postgres_dev"
  ports:
    - 5432:5432
  environment:
    POSTGRES_USER: root
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
    POSTGRES_DB: my-database
```

You can now connect with `postgres:5432` from any other `service` specified in your `docker-compose.yml`. Or connect with `http://localhost:5432` from your host machine. More about [docker compose networking](https://medium.com/@datails/full-stack-development-with-docker-compose-c517ec826696).

Verify by access the container and run something:

```
docker exec -it postgres_dev bash
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U root -P password -d my-database
```

Comment: this helped me to get started, and it is precisely working as described. The problem for me was the "rails db:prepare" statement. So I created manaually the database, and then went (to check) "rails db:create" - it would provide an error message, that database exists. So connectivity is working. Then I did a manaual "rails db:migrate", et voilà, in the psql database I could see the table(s). Hint: as a shortcut I use "docker exec -it <database-docker-host> psql -U postgres"